# Finding the conditional expectation of balls in a urn

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

> An urn contains eight red and ten blue balls. A random batch of eight is
>   chosen. Let $X$ denote the number of red balls in the sample. An additional
>   ball is selected from the remaining ten balls in the urn. Let $Y$ equal $1$ if
>   this ball is red and $0$ if it is blue. Find $E(Y|X=4),E(X|Y=1)$.

I tried doing the problem as follows,

$$\begin{aligned}
&\bullet\,\, E(Y|X=4)=\sum_yyP(Y=y|X=4)=P(Y=1|X=4)=\frac{4}{10}=\frac25.\\
&\bullet\,\, E(X|Y=1)=\sum_xxP(X=x|Y=1)=P(X=1|Y=1)+2P(X=2|Y=1)+3P(X=3|Y=1)+\cdots+7P(X=7|Y=1)=629/120.
\end{aligned}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the part calculating $E(Y|X=4)$ is correct since if $X=4$, then we have 4 red and 6 blue balls remaining. Thus $P(Y=1|X=4)=\frac{4}{10}$ as you obtained.

For the second part, we have two experiments. The first one is drawing a batch of 8 balls, and the second is drawing a single ball. If we do not know anything about the other experiment, the order of these experiments does not matter. Thus let us first think that we draw a single ball from the urn, and then draw a batch of 8 balls. If this case if $Y=1$, then we have 7 red, 10 blue balls remaining in the urn. Thus $E(X|Y=1)=\frac{7}{17}\times 8\approx{3.29}$. Alternatively, we can calculate expected value from $P(X=x|Y=1)$ as follows: $$E(X|Y=1)=\sum_xxP(X=x|Y=1)=\sum_xx\frac{\binom{7}x\binom{10}{8-x}}{\binom{17}{8}}\approx3.29$$

Comment: why are you multiplying by 8?

Comment: Because we are drawing 8 balls. The ratio of red balls in the urn is 7/17. Thus for any batch size we expect that 7/17 of the balls are red. Therefore we find expected number of red balls for batch size of 8 by multiplying 8 by 7/17.