# How to calculate Joint probability distribution? Excesice 2.36 of Simulation - Sheldor Ross

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

The excesise is next:

> An urn contains four white and six black balls. A random sample of
> size 4 is chosen. Let $X$ denote the number of white balls in the
> sample. An additional ball is now selected from the remaining six
> balls in the urn. Let $Y$ equal 1 if this ball is white and 0 if it is
> black.
> Find (a) $E [Y |X = 2]$
> Analogous to the first part of the resolution of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353583/finding-the-conditional-expectation-of-balls-in-a-urn) we have

$$\begin{aligned}
&\bullet\,\, E[Y|X=2]=\sum_yyP(Y=y|X=2)=P(Y=1|X=2)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac13.\\
\end{aligned}$$
Where $P(Y=1|X=2)=P(Z=1)=\frac26$ with $Z$ equal $1$ if this ball is white and $0$ if it is black about the event of having an urn with $2$ white balls and $4$ black balls.

If i want calculate $P(Y=1|X=2)$ without a auxiliar Random Variable $Z$ then $P(Y=1|X=2)=\frac{P(Y=1,X=2)}{P(X=2)}$ but i dont know how to calculate  $P(Y=1,X=2)$.

Comment: There are ${10 \choose 4}=210$ equally likely ways of the taking the balls out in some order.  Of these, ${4 \choose 2}{1\choose 1}{5 \choose 1}=30$ correspond to the event $X=2 \cap Y=1$ while ${4 \choose 2}{6\choose 2}=90$ correspond to the event $X=2$

Comment: First of all Thanks a lot!! I didn't think I could take white's ball that counts X.

Comment: but the event $X=2 \cap Y=1$ should be $\left(\begin{array}{l}3 \\ 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}6 \\ 2\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Why ${3 \choose 1}$? $X=2$ is the number of white balls in the sample of $4$

Comment: it so confuse for me, sorry. you  take 1 of 4 balls with and the an other of 3 ball left. then $\left(\begin{array}{l}3 \\ 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ but why is $\left(\begin{array}{l}5 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Once you have four balls (two of which are white) and one ball (which is white), that leaves you with $10-4-1=5$ balls ($4-2-1=1$ of which is white) to rearrange